# Inserting data to external DataBase

Tags: forms, database, hooks

i'm trying to insert data to a different data base that i created. I've read a lot in the forum, the support documents and other pages but i haven been able to figure it out the problem, can someone give me a hand? point me to a right direction?

first i modified the settings.php like this:

```
<?php
/** ORIGINAL DATA BASE CONNECTION
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'dbname',
      'username' => 'dbuser',
      'password' => 'dbpsw',
      'host' => 'dbhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
*/

/** DOUBLE DATA BASE CONNECTION  */
$databases = array();
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
   'database' => 'dbname',
      'username' => 'dbuser',
      'password' => 'dbpsw',
      'host' => 'dbhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
);
$databases['civilproconstru']['default'] = array(
   'database' => 'name',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'datahost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
);
?>
```

And then in the module i'm creating i'm using this code: (i'm pasting the full module code, the insert is at the end, just in case the error is in the back)

```
<?php
/** START CONFIG MODULE
 * Implements hook_permission().
 */
function project_creator_permission() {
  return array(
    'access project_creator content' => array(
      'title' => t('Access content for the project_creator module'),
    )
  );
}

 /**
 * Agrega a lista de estructura hook_block_info().
 */
function project_creator_block_info() {
  $blocks['project_creator'] = array(
    // The name that will appear in the block list.
    'info' => t('Project Creator'),
    // Default setting.
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Agrega menu en toolbar para "role" contratante hook_menu().
 */
function project_creator_menu() {
  $items['admin/crear_proyecto'] = array(
    'title' => 'Crear Proyecto',
    'description' => 'Crear Proyecto',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('project_creator_insert'),
    'access callback' => 'project_creator_access',
  );

  return $items;
}


function project_creator_access() {
 global $user;
 if (in_array('contratante', array_values($user->roles))){
     return TRUE;
 }
}
 /**
 * END CONFIG MODULE.
 */

/** START PROJECT CREATOR FORM */

function project_creator_insert($form, &$form_state){

    $form['p_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'p_name',
    '#size' => 15
    );

    $form['save'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'save',
    '#submit' => array('project_creator_insert')
    );
    return $form;

db_set_active('civilproconstru'); /* OPEN DATA BASE*/
db_insert('project_info')
->fields(array(
'p_name' => $form_state['values']['p_name'],
))->execute();
drupal_set_message("succesfully saved");
db_set_active(); /*CLOSE DATA BASE*/

}
?>
```

At the end, it shows me the form but when i click save button it seems to be inserting the data but when i check the database it still empty. It doesnt give me any kind of errors on execution.
Thank u for the help...

Comment: The `settings.php` and `db_set_active` code look ok. My guess is that the other database isn't accessible from your host, e.g firewalled on a remote host. Make sure the other db can be connected to from your Drupal web server, e.g via the mysql command line.

Comment: The database is set at the same server of drupal database... it shouldnt be a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any submit callback. You should do any process with the submitted data in a submit callback like that:

```
function project_creator_insert_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  db_set_active('civilproconstru'); /* OPEN DATA BASE*/
  db_insert('project_info')
    ->fields(array(
      'p_name' => $form_state['values']['p_name'],
    ))->execute();
  drupal_set_message("succesfully saved");
  db_set_active(); /*CLOSE DATA BASE*/
}
```

Comment: where is the callback submit on your suggested code? dont see it..

Comment: The function `project_creator_insert_submit()` is the submit callback of your form function `project_creator_insert()`. Take a look at the documentation about [Form generation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7).

Comment: new update... with new error..

Answer (score 1):

Ok! i finally got it! this is the code that worked for me:

`function project_creator_permission() {
  return array(
    'access project_creator content' => array(
      'title' => t('Access content for the project_creator module'),
    )
  );
}
function project_creator_block_info() {
  $blocks['project_creator'] = array(
    // The name that will appear in the block list.
    'info' => t('Project Creator'),
    // Default setting.
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}
function project_creator_menu() {
  $items['admin/crear_proyecto'] = array(
    'title' => 'Crear Proyecto',
    'description' => 'Crear Proyecto',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('project_creator_form'),
    'access callback' => 'project_creator_access',
  );
  return $items;
} 
function project_creator_access() {
 global $user;
 if (in_array('contratante', array_values($user->roles))){
     return TRUE;
 }
}
function project_creator_insert($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['p_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('p_name'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => "Introduzca el nombre del proyecto.",
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );
  return $form;
}
function project_creator_insert_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    /OPEN DATA BASE/
    db_set_active('secondDataBase'); 
    db_insert('test')
        ->fields(array(
        'p_name' => $form_state['values']['p_name'],
        ))->execute();
    drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
db_set_active(); 
/CLOSE DATA BASE/
}
?>`

Answer (score -2):

In the code you are giving submit callback but not writing insert code inside that function. You should write insert code in a function like this:

```
function project_creator_insert($form, &$form_state) {
      db_set_active('civilproconstru');
      db_insert('project_info')
         ->fields(array(
         'p_name' => $form_state['values']['p_name'],
          ))->execute();

      drupal_set_message("succesfully saved");`
      db_set_active();`
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is not correct for the function structure.

Comment: Plus it's just a copy of a already given correct answer.